# Failed to mount Windows share: Connection timed out

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, smb

I am new in Ubuntu14.04 and I would need some help for connect to a server via GUI. I would like to install a software from our Windows server. I created a directory where I want to install the software. I selected "Connect to server" in GUI and copied the server address and clicked to the connect bottom. But I got the following message: `Unhandled error message: Failed to mount Windows share: Connection timed out`

I do not know how I can fix this error. Could someone suggest me a solution? Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: please explain more (e.g. what is **selected "Connect to server" in GUI**)

Comment: I tried connect to server with `nautilus 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.7.`